# Getting SharePoint Online site permissions via PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I registered an app registration via `Register-PnPAzureADApp` which has application level `Sites.FullControl.All` permissions and an admin has consented to it too.

[image: screenshot of permissions]

I then connected using this App Registration: `Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId xxx -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com" -Tenant tenant.onmicrosoft.com -CertificatePath 'path\to\cert.pfx`. This too succeeds.

My end goal is to have another app registration with `Sites.Selected` permissions so I can limit it to specific sites. Before doing that if I were to try and look at the existing permissions of a site via `Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename` it errors:

`Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission: {"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"Access denied",...`

Same deal if I try and set permissions too via `Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission`.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks,
Rakhesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpazureadappsitepermission?view=sharepoint-ps), the required permission is **Microsoft Graph API: Sites.FullControl.All** rather than SharePoint permission.

So you should add this permission in AAD app.

[image]